# How to save preference of Slide_to_act button in flutter for check in and check out

Tags: flutter, android-studio, slider, sharedpreferences

In my code i have created an slider button from slide_to_act lib,
when user press on slide to check in button , the button fetch and update the check in api .
It does the same for Check out button .

when user slides the check in button the the tick shows for 5 sec and then the check out button is visible.

once the check out button slides the button then gets invisible until next day.

this is the basic function of my code .

Now the problem is when I reopen the app then the button also reset to its original state (i.e. Slide to login). I  have tried using the shared preference but I am unable to implement it properly.

....

```
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100),
          child: Builder(builder: (context) {
            final GlobalKey<SlideActionState> key1 = GlobalKey();
            return Container(
              color: widget.outerColor ?? Colors.green,
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 15),
                child: isShowingTick
                    ? Icon(
                  Icons.check,
                  color: Colors.red,
                  size: screenWidth / 10,
                )
                    : SlideAction(
                  text: isCheckingIn ? "Slide to Check In" : "Slide to Check Out",
                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black54,
                    fontSize: screenWidth / 20,
                    fontFamily: "NexaRegular",
                  ),
                  outerColor: Colors.white,
                  innerColor: primary,
                  key: key1,
                  onSubmit: () {
                    if (isCheckingIn) {
                      // If checking in, call markAttendance for Check In
                      widget.markAttendance();
                    } else {
                      // If checking out, call the checkOut function (you need to implement this)
                      widget.markCheckOut();
                    }

                    // Show the tick mark
                    setState(() {
                      isShowingTick = true;
                    });

                    // wait for 5 sec or untilNextDay to check out
                    slideTimer = Timer(
                      isCheckingIn ? Duration(seconds: 5) : waitTimeUntileNextDay(),
                          () {
                        setState(() {
                          isShowingTick = false;
                          isCheckingIn = !isCheckingIn;
                        });

                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
        )
```

...